# ASP.NET Get items from WebService and insert into dropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services

I have a web service which returned all my available projects. I want to take all the projects and to insert them into the drop-down text box. How to do it ?

**(For)**
C# CLass Library:

```
    lblProject = new Label();
    lblProject.Text = "Project";

    ddProject = new DropDownList();

    ddProject.Items.Add(""); <- I want to insert projects here
```

**[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQald.png)**  <=== **Click**

I did this for Console Application and this work, but on console app :D

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SRV.Service1SoapClient client = new SRV.Service1SoapClient();
            SRV.UserDetails details = new SRV.UserDetails();

            details.userName = "Weber";
            details.password = "!Q2w#4r";

            DataTable dt = client.GetProjects(details); // Get the data table.

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------"); 
                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
                {
                    Console.Write(" Item: "); // Print label.
                    Console.WriteLine(item); // Invokes ToString abstract method.
                }
            }

            Console.Read(); // Pause.
        }
```

Thank you previously!

Comment: if you want to add it in a dropdown you must use `new DropDownListItem` and add it to your dropdown
`ddProject.Items.Add(new DropDownListItem(){ item})` 
you need to check on the syntax

Comment: What is Item,  Item = ?

Comment: Item is the datarow in your console app.

Comment: DropDownListItem ??? not found

Comment: Error 3 Cannot initialize object of type 'DropDownListItem' with a collection initializer

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to achieve this. You set your WebMethod to return a List<> of the desired object. Then you just iterate your list and Add them to the DropDownList:

```
List<MyObject> list = GetProjects();
foreach(var l in list)
{
   mydropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text","Value"));
}
```